# How to implement LazyLoad with a scrollable DIV using the Intersection Observer API?

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading, intersection-observer

I am using the LazyLoad library at [github.com/tuupola/lazyload](https://github.com/tuupola/lazyload/blob/2.x/lazyload.js) which works great if you have the body as the root to detect images that come into the viewport.

However, I have a DIV with fixed width and height, actually covering the entire visible browser window. And I need to have lazyload assigned to this DIV, so when the DIV is scrolled, lazy load loads the images inside this DIV, that are coming into the viewport.

With the LazyLoad library it is possible to pass another root:

```
new LazyLoad(images, {
     root: document.querySelector('#wrapper'),
});
```

In my JQuery code I specifically use:

```
$('img.lazyload').lazyload({
    effect: 'fadeIn',
    root: $('#wrapper'),
});
```

But it does not work. Neither with `root: $('#wrapper')[0],`

I also reported this at [github/lazyload](https://github.com/tuupola/lazyload/issues/455) but maybe it is not a bug with the library, however, has to do with the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)?

Comment: The `Intersection Observer API` expects a plain DOM element not a jquery object. Did you try passing `root: $('wrapper').get(0)`? I think this will probably be the issue.

Comment: Yes, I also tried this with `$('wrapper')[0]` but it still did not work.

Comment: Please try providing this object to your root property once `{root: $('#wrapper').get(0),rootMargin: '0px',threshold: 0.5},` and check. I am surmising there is some issue with root object only

Comment: I tried it with your code. It does not work either. -- Could it be that the JQuery Wrapper is the problem? https://github.com/tuupola/lazyload/tree/2.x#jquery-wrapper Maybe I have to pass the `root:` option differently?

Comment: I tried to create a JSFiddle, but due to the iframe setup of JSFiddle it does not seem to trigger lazyload at all: https://jsfiddle.net/z14rumhL/3/ In other words, JSFiddle is not practical to show the issue.

Comment: If you are just trying to lazy load images based on when they are in the viewport.. Why don't you use the browser supported image lazy loading... It is supported in all the browsers now https://web.dev/articles/browser-level-image-lazy-loading  All you have to di is make sure you images have `loading="lazy"`

Comment: **WOW!** This is completely new for me. I didn't know that this exists. I dive into it and report back. Thank you.

Comment: It worked as far as I can see. Thanks a thousand. This comment was golden! ... Can I reward you with the bounty?

Comment: @Avatar they need to post the comment as an answer to do that.

Comment: @Manish can you please put your comment as answer?

Comment: @Avatar sorry for the delay in response.  I'm glad it helped, I had the same feeling the first time I discovered this :) I have added this as an answer with relevant references and details. You can mark the answer as accepted so that other people can also benefit from this.

Answer (score 2):

As of writing this answer lazy loading images is supported by all browsers out of the box, even on android and ios browsers. You do not need to use any third party plugins to achieve the same.

All you need to do is add the attribute `loading="lazy"` on your `img` tags just like below:

```
<img src="imageUri" alt="image" loading="lazy">
```

Browser support:

[image: browser support]

You can find more details here:

[MDN lazy loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading)

[web.dev image lazy loading](https://web.dev/articles/browser-level-image-lazy-loading)

[MDN image loading attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#loading)

Answer (score 0):

I make an example and it works

https://jsbin.com/koyuquduzu/edit?html,css,js,console,output

```
$('.lazyload').lazyload({
    root: app
  })
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Here is a full example of implementing LayLoad with a scrollable `div` using the `Intersection Observer API`.

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="scrollable-container">
    <div class="item">
        <img data-src="image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img data-src="image2.jpg" alt="Image 2">
    </div>
    <!-- Add more items as needed -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.scrollable-container {
    height: 400px; /* Set the desired height */
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// Function to handle image loading
function lazyLoadImage(target) {
    const image = target.querySelector('img');
    const src = image.getAttribute('data-src');
    if (src) {
        image.src = src;
        image.removeAttribute('data-src');
    }
}

// Create an Intersection Observer
const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            lazyLoadImage(entry.target);
            observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
    });
});

// Get all items to observe
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

// Observe each item
items.forEach(item => {
    observer.observe(item);
});

// Initiating Lazy Load
const initialVisibleItems = document.querySelectorAll('.item:is(:in-viewport)');
initialVisibleItems.forEach(item => {
    lazyLoadImage(item);
});
```

The `:is(:in-viewport)` selector is a hypothetical example of how you might select elements initially in the viewport using a CSS selector. In practice, you might need to implement this logic manually based on your specific requirements.